# How to Return Data From JavaScript Promise Into Array

Tags: javascript, csv, promise

I'm trying to extract data from an online .csv file and when I do my function returns a promise. What I would like to do is take data from the promise and append (or push) it to an array so that I can use it in my visualization.

the issue I'm facing is `dataFinal` is empty and `someData` only contains values inside the `.then()` function.

Any tips on how to get data into my arrays would be much appreciated!

Here's what I currently have:

```
async function getData() {
        const nytdata = await d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us.csv")
    return nytdata
    }

let nytdata = getData();
var someData = [];
var datafFinal =  someData.then(function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      someData.push({
        date: data[i]["date"],
        value: data[i]["cases"],
        group: data[i]["date"].getMonth()
      });
    }
    return someData
});
console.log(datafFinal)
```

Comment: `data` is undefined. I don't see it being declared

Comment: That is the only way to get data out. Async is async all the way down.

Comment: Did you mean `nytdata.then()`?

Comment: And `data` should probably be `result`

Comment: Please take a look at the answers here (scroll down past the ones about jquery): [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). The array isn't your issue, the issue is that you're trying synchronous calls on data that depends on async calls. Once you've got a Promise, you need to keep using promises (or async/await) through the rest of that logic.

Comment: `console.log(datafFinal)` is being executed before the callback.